# Laravel Controller and helper file: Undefined variable in view

Tags: php, laravel, web

I have an issue trying to use in my controller a function located in an helper file which is auto-loaded. I already used helper functions in some controllers but this function doesn't work and I don't understand why. I have different resources that use a similar code for the controller index() function for example. So my aim is to make functions that I can use in different controllers in this way.

Here's the error I get: "Undefined variable: articles" in the view file ArticlesIndex.blade.php

Helper function:

```
function res_index($collection,$viewName,$varName) {
    if(!$collection->isEmpty()) {
        $collection->take(10);
        return view($viewName, compact($varName));
    } else {
        return 'Nothing';
    }
}
```

And here's my index() function located in the controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $articles = Article::all();
    return res_index($articles,'ArticlesIndex','articles');
}
```

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Return value, returned by `res_index`:

```
return res_index($articles,'ArticlesIndex','articles');
```